# How to do multiple count in a single query in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

So I have this code:

```
db.collection.find( { sex: 'Male' } ).count()
```

and what I want to do is also count `sex: 'Female'` at the same time instead of

```
db.collection.find( { sex: 'Male' } ).count()
db.collection.find( { sex: 'Female' } ).count()
```

Is there a way to do it in a single query? Because I am generating a pie chart based on their length. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple Counts with single query in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52088666/multiple-counts-with-single-query-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 9):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {"$group" : {_id:"$sex", count:{$sum:1}}}
])
```